# Create, name, and populate new workbook with data

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with two columns of data. Column A has the desired new workbook names and Column B's adjacent cell has the data I want in the new work book.

So if `032411` is in column A and `50` is in column B then the macro would create a new workbook named `032411` and `50` would be in cell `A1` of that workbook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Sub CreateBooks()

    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim oWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

    'Added to avoid messages asking to confirm overwriting
    '   previous existent files with same name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each oCell In Range("A:A")

        If oCell.Value = "" Then Exit For

        Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        'If the cell value contains only the file name (instead of the whole path
        '   the file needs to be saved) it will save into MyDocuments folder
        oWorkbook.Close True, oCell.Value

    Next oCell

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

In case you have several files to generate, you can alternatively use the `application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Comment: Thanks Tiago.  That was a huge leap forward.  It just needs tweaked now.  The macro generated all new workbooks but did not rename them with the value from cell A1 and save it as such.  I tried to update it as suggested but can't seam to get it right.

Comment: Also worth noting is the file name MMDDYY includes a zero at the beginning in many cases and uses the custom cell format.  When the cell is clicked on the formula bar shows the date as M/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Following your example, we need to save a file named as 032411.xls, right? I believe it's already happening, I'd need a clarification about what you need / what we have now and the diff between what you need / what we have.

Comment: When I copy/paste the macro I get runtime error 1004: cannot access the file 'C:\....My Documents\3\26\74C4B900.  The 3\26\ after my documents is why I think it is having a problem with the number format.  When I hit debug it highlights oWorkbook.Close True, oCell.Value.  When I delete that, it will generate new workbooks with the data from column B but does not save them with the value of column A.  Each workbook is named generically by excel as book2, book3, etc.

Comment: Yes, probably. You cannot have a slash within a file name. From where this \3\26 is coming from?